# No redirect or component for specified path angular2

Tags: angular

Given a routes array with path empty string how do I make the path basically do nothing? I don't want to redirect or load a component. I realize I can just take the object out of the array and then the app will work fine, however it creates a lot of errors in the console for something that should be able to be overridden with some method like this

```
[
    {
        path: '',
        component: null
    },
    {
        path: 'cow-group',
        component: GroupSelector,
        outlet: 'comp1'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load a component that displays nothing.

```
{
    path: '',
    component: DummyComponent
},
```

Comment: Just did that which works, is there another way besides creating another component?

Comment: No, but you can use the same `DummyComponent` multiple times if you have other routers where you don't want to display anything in a specific router-outlet.

Comment: Thanks, I guess at the very least it is reusable